# Picking a random string index between two string indexes in an ArrayList (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist

First off a little background about this program I am making. NCAA March Madness is about to begin and I thought that it would be cool to make a program that takes the teams that are in the tournament and randomly pick winnners for each round until there is one definitive winner. How I planned to do this was make one array list for each of the four regions of 16 teams. Then it would take the first two indexes (mimicking a basketball game) and would pick a random number (which signifies the winner). My question is how do I get the for loop to iterate through all the indexes while only comparing the applicable indexes (i.e. indexes 0&1, 2&3, 4&5, etc.) and deleting one random index from one of the groups of two indexes in the array list.
The problem right now when I run the code it just deletes every third index instead of deleting one random one in either group of two indexes
P.S. The code above is only for one round of one of the four regions, for questioning purposes.
P.S.S I am rather new to programming, so please excuse my crude code.
Thanks for any help!! It is greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
public class BracketGeneratorV2
{
    public static void main (String [] Args)
    {
        Scanner userin = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rnum = new Random();

        ArrayList<String> eastSide = new ArrayList<String>();


        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            eastSide.add(userin.nextLine());
        }

        int x = -2;
        for (int i = 0; i < eastSide.size()/2; i++)
        {
            x += 2;

            int matchupWinner = rnum.nextInt(1)+0;
            if (matchupWinner == 0)
            {   
                eastSide.remove(eastSide.get(x));
            }
            else if (matchupWinner == 1)
            {
                eastSide.remove(eastSide.get(x+1));
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < eastSide.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(eastSide.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using a debugger, they are great for stepping through your code and making it easier to understand where your program is getting derailed.

Comment: The expression `int matchupWinner = rnum.nextInt(1)+0` may always be returning 0. According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt--) nextInt returns an integer between 0, inclusive and the parameter, _exclusive_.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So would it be possible to generate a random double between 0 and 1 and then use if, else if, else to see if the random double is </>/= to 0.5?

Comment: *"So would it be possible to generate a random double between 0 and 1 and then use if"* why would you want to do that? You need a random *index* which is a *non negative integer*, so all you have to do is to apply a bigger parameter to `Random.nextInt()`.

Comment: The function of the random integer is to pick one of the two teams (kind of like a coin toss) so if I were to make the end parameter of Random.nextInt() bigger couldn't it come up with more than 2 random integers and not be able to pick either team. Excuse me if im not fully understanding how Random.nextInt() works

Comment: If you are matching two teams at a time, I think I would just take the next Boolean from the `Random` to decide whether the first or the second team wins.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `int matchupWinner = rnum.nextInt(1) + 0` to `int matchupWinner = rnum.nextInt(2)` That's what Aj Johnson was talking about in the comments. This is because the latter will return 0 or 1, while the former will only return 0 (because the argument is not included in the range).